# VSCode: Automatically run npm script on starting debugging of a web project

Tags: debugging, npm, visual-studio-code

So here is my VS code `launch.json` file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:4321",
            "port": 9222,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want is run `npm start` command right before debugging begins i.e running dev server then launching a Chrome instance and navigating to the provided url.

So, I added the following snippet to the config file and ran the debug:

```
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
            "runtimeArgs": [
               "start"
            ]
```

but I got the this error:

```
Attribute runtimeExecutable does not exist ('npm')
```

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution: I need a `preLaunchTask`

`launch.json`:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            ...
            // This runs dev server before debugger
            "preLaunchTask": "start-dev-server",
        }
    ]
}
```

`tasks.json`:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "start-dev-server",
            "type": "npm",
            "script": "start",
            "isBackground": true,
            "problemMatcher": {
                "owner": "npm",
                "background": {
                    "activeOnStart": true,
                     "beginsPattern": ".*",
                     "endsPattern": "Finished.+"
                },
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "",
                }
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: I used this, but it does not complete, therefore it doesn't go back and start the chrome window

Comment: it does not run `npm start` in the background. vs-code waits for npm start to complete before starting chrome.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

tasks.json

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "npm",
            "script": "dev",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "label": "npm: dev",
            "detail": "vite --port 4000"
        }
    ]
}
```

launch.json

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch via Chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:4000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "preLaunchTask": "npm: dev", 
        }
    ]
}
```

Then just press F5 or click the Start Debugging button.